# how to switch records looking at source-of-truth if available or not depending on availability in other sources in the database

Tags: t-sql, switch-statement, datasource

In SSMS,
we have 4 different sources and every numerical records in one fact table.

Business wants me to switch records in availability to prioritize

Do we have actuals records or projections, if it's projections then;

First, do we have records available in sourcedId = 4 then bring the record
if we have in sourceId = 4, I want to see the most recent record.
Second, If we don't have any record available in sourceId = 4, go the sourceId = 1
and bring me the record

if it's not projections then it's actuals, so use sourceId = 2 and bring me the record.

I want to understand what approach I can use, I have never done anything like this before.
any idea, any example very much appreciated !

thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   ID          INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,SCENARIO_ID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
  ,GUID_ID     VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
  ,RECORD_TYPE VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL
  ,VALUE       NUMERIC(4,2) NOT NULL
  ,APPROVED_ON DATE 
  ,SOURCE_ID   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,IS_APPROVED VARCHAR(8)
);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SCENARIO_ID,GUID_ID,RECORD_TYPE,VALUE,APPROVED_ON,SOURCE_ID,IS_APPROVED) VALUES (1,'sdfgsdfgsdfg','sdfsd1231','actuals',7.64,NULL,2,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SCENARIO_ID,GUID_ID,RECORD_TYPE,VALUE,APPROVED_ON,SOURCE_ID,IS_APPROVED) VALUES (2,'fncvbdfsgdfg','sdfgsd213','actuals',6.78,NULL,2,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SCENARIO_ID,GUID_ID,RECORD_TYPE,VALUE,APPROVED_ON,SOURCE_ID,IS_APPROVED) VALUES (3,'fghcvbfncvb','sdfgsdfg4234','actuals',5.92,NULL,2,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SCENARIO_ID,GUID_ID,RECORD_TYPE,VALUE,APPROVED_ON,SOURCE_ID,IS_APPROVED) VALUES (4,'fdsgsdhsdf','sdfgf234','actuals',5.06,NULL,2,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SCENARIO_ID,GUID_ID,RECORD_TYPE,VALUE,APPROVED_ON,SOURCE_ID,IS_APPROVED) VALUES (5,'vbncvbncvbn','dfghdf4534','actuals',4.2,NULL,2,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SCENARIO_ID,GUID_ID,RECORD_TYPE,VALUE,APPROVED_ON,SOURCE_ID,IS_APPROVED) VALUES (6,'dfghgfdhfgdh','ncbnc2342','actuals',3.34,NULL,2,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SCENARIO_ID,GUID_ID,RECORD_TYPE,VALUE,APPROVED_ON,SOURCE_ID,IS_APPROVED) VALUES (7,'bvnmvbnmv','fbhdfg4567','projections',2.34,NULL,4,'DENIED');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SCENARIO_ID,GUID_ID,RECORD_TYPE,VALUE,APPROVED_ON,SOURCE_ID,IS_APPROVED) VALUES (8,'srejtsskdjfhgsk','fbhdfg4567','projections',2.56,'9/5/2023',4,'APPROVED');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SCENARIO_ID,GUID_ID,RECORD_TYPE,VALUE,APPROVED_ON,SOURCE_ID,IS_APPROVED) VALUES (9,'skdjfhgskjdfhg','fghdfgh3453','projections',2.78,NULL,4,'DENIED');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SCENARIO_ID,GUID_ID,RECORD_TYPE,VALUE,APPROVED_ON,SOURCE_ID,IS_APPROVED) VALUES (10,'oswiertsdfjg','fghdfgh3453','projections',3,NULL,1,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SCENARIO_ID,GUID_ID,RECORD_TYPE,VALUE,APPROVED_ON,SOURCE_ID,IS_APPROVED) VALUES (11,'erthskljdjg','cfghfg3453','projections',3.22,'9/3/2023',4,'APPROVED');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SCENARIO_ID,GUID_ID,RECORD_TYPE,VALUE,APPROVED_ON,SOURCE_ID,IS_APPROVED) VALUES (12,'dfghdfgh','cfghfg3453','projections',3.44,'9/2/2023',4,'APPROVED');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SCENARIO_ID,GUID_ID,RECORD_TYPE,VALUE,APPROVED_ON,SOURCE_ID,IS_APPROVED) VALUES (13,'cxvbxcvbxcvb','cfghfg3453','projections',3.66,NULL,4,'DENIED');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SCENARIO_ID,GUID_ID,RECORD_TYPE,VALUE,APPROVED_ON,SOURCE_ID,IS_APPROVED) VALUES (14,'dfsgdfgxdbx','dfghdf345','projections',3.88,NULL,1,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SCENARIO_ID,GUID_ID,RECORD_TYPE,VALUE,APPROVED_ON,SOURCE_ID,IS_APPROVED) VALUES (15,'erstdfgdcbx','fdghdfghd454','projections',4.1,NULL,4,'DENIED');
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: @habo hey thank you for this, but I can't post screenshots here. system doesn't let me to do this.

Comment: You shouldn't post images of data, DDL, queries or other fundamentally textual information unless you are asking about the font, color, ... . Providing sample data (with DDL) and expected results helps us help you. Posting "got stuff, want stuff" doesn't give us much to go on. Please edit your question to include the text and remove the image.

Comment: this is not the best way to explain my query, but this is the idea in sql. better now ?

Comment: Whats the desired result to your data posted in the question?

Comment: @jigga I don't have any example, I'm trying to solve this one above as a sample. 
I wish I could share gif / picture to the comment to show

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a try. But since the expectations are not clear, not sure if it's a good one:

```
SELECT 
        M.*
FROM mytable AS M
INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT MAX(approved_on) AS APPROVED_ON
                FROM mytable
                WHERE RECORD_TYPE = 'PROJECTIONS' AND SOURCE_ID = 4
            ) AS T
    ON M.RECORD_TYPE = 'PROJECTIONS' AND M.SOURCE_ID = 4 AND M.APPROVED_ON = T.APPROVED_ON
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE RECORD_TYPE = 'PROJECTIONS' AND SOURCE_ID = 4)

UNION ALL

SELECT 
        *
FROM mytable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE RECORD_TYPE = 'PROJECTIONS' AND SOURCE_ID = 4) AND RECORD_TYPE = 'PROJECTIONS' AND SOURCE_ID = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
        *
FROM mytable
WHERE RECORD_TYPE = 'ACTUALS' AND SOURCE_ID = 2;
```

The first block selects the most recent records for `projections` with `SOURCE_ID = 4` if there is one.

If not, the second block selects all records for `projections` with `SOURCE_ID = 1`. If there is `SOURCE_ID = 4` it doesn't return anything.

Finaly the 3rd block selects all `actuals` with `SOURCE_ID = 2`.